# Laravel HasManyThrough with a where statments

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I'm trying to use the `HasManyThrought` relation with a `where` statement, but I don't know how to achieve that goal.

So I have these tables:

```
Users:
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | James |
+----+-------+

Orders:
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | state      |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | 1       | complete   |
+----+---------+------------+
| 2  | 1       | incomplete |
+----+---------+------------+
| 3  | 1       | pending    |
+----+---------+------------+

Order Items:
+----+----------+--------+
| id | order_id | name   |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | 1        | Mac    |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | 1        | Tablet |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | 2        | Laptop |
+----+----------+--------+
```

And now I want to fetch the user's order items, So I'll do something like this:

```
public function items()
{
    $this-hasManyThrough(Item::class, Order::class)
}
```

But! what If I want to fetch **only** the items that their order is stated as `complete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all items of authenticated user with `complete` state, use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$items = Item::whereHas('order', function($q) {
    $q->where('state', 'complete')
      ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
})->get();
```

Don't forget to define `order()` relationship in the `Item` model:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```